# How to make a copy of a local wordpress build in MAMP?

Tags: local-installation, git

I've been working on my site locally using MAMP and installing the wordpress folder in htdocs.

However i wanted to make a copy of the site so that i can test another solution.

I can't do a git init in my htdocs folder so i copied my build from my htdocs folder to my desktop and initiated git and all works well.

However when i access the copy of my wordpress build (which is in another directory) and i start to click around the links don't respond to the new build but rather the original which is in my htdocs folder.

This gives me the impression that:

- a) only the homepage is recognizing the new copy but my internal
  links, even though they are nothing more than /category/place..etc is
  generic,don't specify the domain.
- b) If i make changes to the new copy it will in fact be changing my
  original.
- c) on my next project i should start with a git repo and NOT work
  within the htdocs folder

Comment: Have you changed `siteurl` and `home` in the `wp_options` table?

Comment: Why can't you run `git init` in the `htdocs` folder?

Comment: @murdaugh i haven't done that i'll look into it.

Comment: @s_ha_dum that's a good question and i've tried but can't seem to locate it in bash even when I "ls -a" that directory won't come up within my "Applications" directory. I truly don't understand why i can't dig deeper into my Applications folder and find my htdocs, so really that's the reason i've been unsuccessful at initializing git within my htdocs but that would be my preferred choice. Thanks.

Comment: Never used MAMP, and try to avoid Macs as much as possible, but [the docs say your files should be at `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/`](http://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/faq.html) at least by default. Have you changed the default?

Comment: I have about 20 wordpress installs on my MAMP (pro) setup, all using local hostnames (like wordpress.dev) - They're all git repos and they're running outside of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ - as long as your disk location is set correctly, you should be able to put your webroot wherever you want and run `git init` to create a repo.

Comment: @murdaugh good to know and next time i'll do it this way for sure but for.

Comment: @s_ha_dum i hear ya man, i gotta say i love my mac but windows has WAMP so i'm sure it probably works the same way, and yes you are correct the files should be at htdocs by default but as murdaugh pointed out it appears the root folder can be anywhere so long as MAMP/WAMP is setup correctly. Thanks to both.